# Buying used heat pump/AC

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air, heat-pump

I'm planning to buy and install a used heat pump/AC at some point in the near future (probably looking for sellers on Craigslist or similar), and want to know what I should look for to know if the equipment is in proper working order. Are there any common problems that can be detected by visual inspection of a system that's not put together? Any way to do a pressure/leak test before buying? And any considerations for what type of refrigerant to prefer (other than R-22 being expensive and less convenient to get)?

Comment: Don't get a system that uses R-22. They are limiting its manufacture, so it will be nearly impossible to get in the near future.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless the equipment is actually installed, you're going to have to trust the seller.  You'll also want to have a professional install the unit, unless you have all the tools and knowledge required to do so.

Comment: My plan was to get the tools I need and do the installation work and just have a certified AC tech (who's retired and not physically able to do much of the work himself) look it over and finish it up. Ductwork is already there from an old furnace system I'm taking out, so in theory the installation is just running the refrigerant lines and doing the electrical work - my understanding is these systems run on 240V rather than 120V, right?

Comment: My concern is the refrigerant lines, and charging the system.   Special tools and knowledge are required to charge the system, and it's very easy to mess up. Not to mention the fact that you may have trouble getting your hands on the refrigerant.

Comment: Yeah, charging is something I'm planning to get help with ("finish it up").